# why subdomain on iis not working?

Tags: iis, iis-7, subdomain

I am trying to add sub domain on local IIS and use [this](http://www.brettgil.com/techie-stuff/steps-to-setup-a-localhost-sub-domain-in-iis-7) construction. i search in google and find many other article like this but it not work on my PC.
how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Though the steps are not documented quite well, it should work. Describe what is the error you met, or nobody can help.

Comment: i found my silly mistake... and it was my proxy... it was on  :(

Comment: Post your finding as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It caused by my proxy. it was on and my DNS changes was not affected properly.
I disconnect my proxy (psiphon3 in my situation) an every thing work like a charm.